# Why is my date picker in android displaying the year wrong?

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

I have created this datePicker for my app and I have it set to show a Toast once the user picks a date. This is just a test before I move on to anything else, however, when I pick a date it shows the wrong year. For example when I choose today's date, the Toast will display: "Date is: 3917-04-10".

```
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
{
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
Date start;
String entered_Start;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int yyyy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yyyy, mm, dd);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yyyy, int mm, int dd)
{
    start = new Date(yyyy,mm,dd);
    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    entered_Start = dateFormatter.format(start);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Date is: "+ entered_Start, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I fixed it. All I had to do was change this line:

```
start = new Date(yyyy,mm,dd);
```

To this Line:

```
start = calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: Did you set the `dateFormat`? by default datepicker dateformat is `Default: "mm/dd/yy"`

Comment: The deprecated `Date` constructor that you use, adds 1900 to year. So if you pass 2017 to it, you get a date in 3917. If you should use it (not recommended), you would need to pass 117 for 2017.

Answer (score 1):

this `new Date()` was deprecated, you can (better) use `Calendar`

your code will be like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,yyyy);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dd);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,mm);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
entered_Start  = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Date is: "+ entered_Start, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use `new Date(yyyy,mm,dd);` use

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, yyyy);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, mm);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dd);
    c.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Date` constructor is deprecated. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) you can see that

```
This constructor was deprecated in API level 1. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date)
```

Better to use setters of `Calendar` object like you use getters before creating dialog.

```
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, yyyy);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, mm);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dd);
```

Yes, you can use `new Date(yyyy - 1900,mm,dd)`. But it is bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
int day = datePicker1.getDayOfMonth();
int mon = datePicker1.getMonth();
int ye = datePicker1.getYear();

            SimpleDateFormat dt=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date d=new Date(ye,mon,day);
            String sdt=dt.format(d);

            System.out.println("Date>>>>>>"+sdt);//Date>>>>>>3922-02-28

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Calendar.YEAR, ye);
            c.set(Calendar.MONTH, mon);
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
            //c.getTime();
            System.out.println("Date<<<<"+dt.format(c.getTime())); //Date<<<<2022-02-28
```